# HERE Routing API - Getting 403

Tags: here-api

I am trying to run the simple example from quick start https://developer.here.com/cn/documentation/routing/topics/request-a-simple-route.html. I enter my app ID and my app code but I keep getting:

```
curl 'https://route.hereapi.cn/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?app_id=APP_ID&app_code=APP_CODE&waypoint0=geo!52.5,13.4&waypoint1=geo!52.5,13.45&mode=fastest;car;traffic:disabled'
{"error":"Forbidden","error_description":"These credentials do not authorize access. Please contact your customer representative or submit a request here https://developer.here.com/contact-us to upgrade your account. You can also get valid credentials by registering for a free trial license on https://developer.here.com."}
```

My project is PROD-edc776ee-a821-4156-8c1c-ebceb30a27e5. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation you are referring and the api link you are using are china specific. This will work only if you access it from China. If not, then you have to use the normal Routing API documentation - https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/topics/request-a-simple-route.html